# Factorize Parametric Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, factorization

Is there a possibility to factorize a parametric polynomial expression - meaning that the coefficients are defined as parameters, and not as specific numbers?

My example - a polynomial in `s`, with `R1, ..., R5` and `C1, ..., C2` being parameters:

```
LP2nTfDen = R1 R4 + R4 R5 + C2 R1 R2 R4 s + C1 R1 R3 R5 s + C2 R2 R4 R5 s -
            C1 C2 R1 R2 R4 R5 s^2
```

I'd like *Mathematica* to transform the expression in the form `(A + s) (B + s)` ..., `A`, `B`, etc. being expressions of `R1, ..., R5`, `C1`, `C2`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your resulting expression will have a unit coefficient for the highest power. In this case you can do :

```
expr = Times @@ (s - Solve[LP2nTfDen/Last@CoefficientList[LP2nTfDen, {s}] == 0, s][[All,1, 2]]) ;

expr == LP2nTfDen/Last@CoefficientList[LP2nTfDen, {s}] // Simplify

(* True *)
```